# Read data from database and write into output .txt file in spring

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I just want to query data from database and write it into an output file. How can I achieve this using spring batch?

Comment: Could you not just use JDBC and then write the result using BufferedWriter?

Comment: Why do you need spring batch to do this? You could very well query the DB with spring jdbc and then write the output to a file.

Comment: Do you have sample code for buffered writer?

Comment: What have you tried? Consider reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: How to write jdbctemplate to get resuleset from query?

Answer (score 1):

See this blog, it's great for beginners!
http://www.mkyong.com/spring/

There the author gives a clear and easy example on how to use JDBC
http://www.mkyong.com/spring/maven-spring-jdbc-example/

Then like Ranu Jain correctly said you use JDBCTemplate in your class to read the information (execute the query you want) by injecting it has a property.

Follow mkyong example and it will be easy.

Answer (score 0):

If you will JDBC template in your context.xml then you will get DB connection by injecting jdbcTemplate in your processor and by using File object you can write the data in any file

```
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: As i am new to spring, i am not able to ubderstand above code

Comment: You can refer this below link for how to right JDBC template. http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html.                                         For Spring batch File you can refer     http://java.dzone.com/news/spring-batch-hello-world-1